# Calling a overridden method of subclass from superclass error?

Tags: java, superclass

I have following two set of Java code. The first one works but the second one doesn't?

```
package animal;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal createAnimals = new Animal();
        createAnimals.printInfo();
        String userInput = createAnimals.userInputHandle();
        Fishes a = new Fishes();

        switch (userInput) {
            case ("shark"):
                a.printInfo();
        }
    }

    private void printInfo() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Animal Kingdom.");
    }

    private String userInputHandle() {
        String userInput;
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select animal from the "
                + "following list"
                + "\n1.Dog\n2.Cat\n3.Snake\n4.Frog"
                + "\n5.Human\n6.Shark\n7.Sea Gulls");
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

        return userInput;
    }
}

class Fishes extends Animal {

    public void printInfo() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shark belongs to Fish subclass of Animal kingdom.");

    }
}
```

and second set of code is

```
package animal;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal createAnimals = new Animal();
        createAnimals.printInfo();
        String userInput = createAnimals.userInputHandle();

        ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        animalList.add(new Fishes());

        switch (userInput) {
            case ("shark"):
                animalList.get(0).printInfo();
            case ("sea gulls"):
        }
    }

    private void printInfo() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Animal Kingdom.");
    }

    private String userInputHandle() {

        String userInput;
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select animal from the "
                + "following list"
                + "\n1.Dog\n2.Cat\n3.Snake\n4.Frog"
                + "\n5.Human\n6.Shark\n7.Sea Gulls");
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

        return userInput;
    }
}

class Fishes extends Animal {

    public void printInfo() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shark belongs to Fish subclass of Animal kingdom.");

    }
}
```

Here the overridden method `printInfo` is not invoked with `animalList.get(0).printInfo()` instead class animal's method is invoked? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

`#printInfo` is `private` in `Animal` and cannot be overriden by a subclass, you should make it `protected`.

Comment: +1 Also, it's a good idea to use the @Override annotation whenever you're intending to override a method - in this case your IDE and/or the java compiler would then flag this error.

Comment: it solved but is it like this generally ? What are other possibility ? What should be the modifier of method in superclass so that it can be overridden in subclass ?

Comment: @user1837224 Use `protected` for methods that should be overriden in subclasses, but not visible outside.

Answer (score 1):

**private** methods are not **overridden** in sub-class . 
change

```
   private void printInfo() {
```

to

```
  public  void printInfo() {
```

or

```
  protected  void printInfo() {
```

In *Animal Class*.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the object into the subclass i.e. (Fishes)animalList.get(0).printInfo();

Note before casting it is always a good idea to check what type an object is using an if statement using the instanceof comparator.